# Is it better to divide fragments between two activities, say between MainActivity and another some activity:(Performance)?

Tags: java, android

so if i have 10 fragments i will put 6 in MainActivity and the other in the second activiy
the idea is to enhance performance(decrease the work on MainActivity).

Comment: I think this question is a little too ill-defined to warrant a proper answer, but let me ask you this: When those 10 fragments are sitting there in `MainActivity`, what "work" do you think is being done? What resources are being taxed?

Comment: i am using a navigation drawer to navigate between fragments, and because there is a lot of fragments, i am defined a new activity, and one of the fragments contains a recyclerview, so when the user click on an item the new activity launched instead of replace current fragment with a new fragment. (the big question is that matter in context of performance, since the logcat saying that there is a heavy work on main thread?

Comment: OK, so the logcat says too much work is being done. Does it say that when you're _creating_ the fragments, when you're _switching_ the fragments, or when you're _using_ one particular fragment?

Comment: No it doesn't , so your answer that it is not matter if i am creating my fragments in one activity or multiple activities(that doesn't affect performance of my app).

Comment: All I'm getting at is that a `Fragment` is relatively lightweight, and it doesn't really cost much of anything to have it just sitting offscreen/invisible. When it's rendering, animating, doing database lookups -- then it is using resources.